# Auto & manual carousel combination HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, slideshow

I've created a 300x600 html banner using 4 frames and I'm trying to get it to transition through the frames automatically, but also give the user the option to manually scroll through them. I've got the arrows working, and the transitions working, but I can't seem to make the circles along the bottom of the banner clickable. I want the user to be able to click the 3rd circle and the banner to show the 3rd frame.

```
<div class="container">

  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag1)">
    <img class="frames" src="01.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag2)">
    <img class="frames" src="02.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag3)">
    <img class="frames" src="03.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag4)">
    <img class="frames" src="04.jpg">
  </a>

  <div id ="leftArrow" class="arrows"></div>
  <div id ="rightArrow" class="arrows"></div>

  <div class="circles">
    <span class="circle dot" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="circle" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="circle" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    <span class="circle" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></span>
  </div>

</div>


<script>

  // IMAGE SLIDES & CIRCLES ARRAYS, & COUNTER
  var imageSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('frames');
  var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
  var leftArrow = document.getElementById('leftArrow');
  var rightArrow = document.getElementById('rightArrow');
  var counter = 0;

  // HIDE ALL IMAGES FUNCTION
  function hideImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageSlides.length; i++) {
      imageSlides[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }
  }

  // REMOVE ALL DOTS FUNCTION
  function removeDots() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageSlides.length; i++) {
      circles[i].classList.remove('dot');
    }
  }

  function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
  }

  // SINGLE IMAGE LOOP/CIRCLES FUNCTION
  function imageLoop() {
    var currentImage = imageSlides[counter];
    var currentDot = circles[counter];
    currentImage.classList.add('visible');
    removeDots();
    currentDot.classList.add('dot');
    counter++;
  }

  // LEFT & RIGHT ARROW FUNCTION & CLICK EVENT LISTENERS
  function arrowClick(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target == leftArrow) {
      clearInterval(imageSlideshowInterval);
      hideImages();
      removeDots();
      if (counter == 1) {
        counter = (imageSlides.length - 1);
        imageLoop();
        imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 4000);
      } else {
        counter--;
        counter--;
        imageLoop();
        imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 4000);
      }
    } 
    else if (target == rightArrow) {
      clearInterval(imageSlideshowInterval);
      hideImages();
      removeDots();
      if (counter == imageSlides.length) {
        counter = 0;
        imageLoop();
        imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 4000);
      } else {
        imageLoop();
        imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 4000);
      }
    }
  }

  leftArrow.addEventListener('click', arrowClick);
  rightArrow.addEventListener('click', arrowClick);


  // IMAGE SLIDE FUNCTION
  function slideshow() {
    if (counter < imageSlides.length) {
      imageLoop();
    } else {
      counter = 0;
      hideImages();
      imageLoop();
    }
  }

  // SHOW FIRST IMAGE, & THEN SET & CALL SLIDE INTERVAL
  setTimeout(slideshow, 0);
  var imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 4000);

</script>


<style>

  .container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .frames {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  /* add 'visible' class via Javascript */
  .visible {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .arrows {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .arrows:hover {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }

  #leftArrow {
    background-image: url(arrow_1.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 259px;
  }

  #rightArrow {
    background-image: url(arrow_2.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 259px;
  }

  .circles {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 410px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .circle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .dot {
    background-color: #13b9ab;
  }


</style>
```

Comment: also add html and css

Comment: Do you want to code the slider by yourself, or is a Library like slick.js an opportunity for you too ?

Comment: @FloriandeVille I'd like to code the slider by myself

Comment: @Hammadtariq Just added it :)

Comment: I set it up in jsfiddle and got "showDivs is not defined"

Comment: @Sara j  your function` currentDiv(n)`  is missing

Comment: @Hammadtariq currentDiv(n) is defined and has one line - a call to showDivs.  showDivs is not defined (js console told me that, and ctrl+f didn't turn up a function declaration).

Comment: @MaKR thanks for correction i also means that `showDivs()` in  currentDiv(n) is missing